# need to implement datepicker appear and disappear functionality in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6

Need to implement datepicker appear and disappear functionality in react js please help me to implement that thing In my last question typescript was mention in this code it is completely on react please help me to appear and disappear functionality

https://codesandbox.io/s/abacus-date-picker-forked-7co0w?file=/src/components/date-field/DateField.scss

**I am working on that file to implement datepicker appear/disappear functionality
If I click on the input field, the dropdown appears and stays visible, whereas when I click on the text input, or selecting date the dropdown briefly appears**
Widget.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import moment from 'moment';
import { find as _find } from 'lodash';
import { Dropdown } from './dropdown/Dropdown';
import { DateField } from './date-field/DateField';
import { MonthNavigator } from './month-navigator/MonthNavigator';
import './Widget.scss';

const MIN_YEAR = 1900;
const MAX_YEAR = moment().year() + 5;

export class Widget extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const date = props.date || moment();
    this.state = {
      date,
      day: date.date(),
      month: date.month(),
      year: date.year(),
      selectedDay: 10,
      selectedMonth: 2,
      selectedYear: 2019,
      dropdownHeight: 200,
    };
  }

  // createDay({ dayNumber, startDay }) {
  //   const { day, month, year, date, selectedDay } = this.state;

  //   let state = '';
  //   if (month === date.month() && year === date.year()) {
  //     state = dayNumber === selectedDay
  //       ? 'Widget-day--selected'
  //       : (dayNumber === day
  //         ? 'Widget-day--current'
  //         : ''
  //       );
  //   }
  //   const style = {};
  //   if (startDay) {
  //     style = { ...style, gridColumnStart: startDay};
  //     startDay = 0;
  //   }
  //   return (
  //     <div className={`Widget-day ${state}`} onClick={() => this.changeDay({ day: dayNumber)}
  //       style={style}
  //       key={dayNumber}>
  //       {dayNumber}
  //     </div>
  //   );
  // }

  /**
   * 
   * @param {object} param
   * @param {string} param.type   Can be: 'previous' | 'next' | `null` where `null` is current
   */
  createDays() {
    const daysInWeek = 7;
    const { day, month, year, date, selectedDay, selectedMonth, selectedYear } = this.state;
    const list = [];
    const daysInCurrentMonth = moment([year, month, day]).daysInMonth();
    const daysInPreviousMonth = moment([year, month, day]).subtract(1, 'month').daysInMonth();
    let startDay = moment([year, month, 1]).day();

    const numPreviousDaysShown = Math.max(startDay - 1, 0);
    let numNextDaysShown = daysInWeek - (daysInCurrentMonth + numPreviousDaysShown) % daysInWeek;
    if (numNextDaysShown === daysInWeek) {
      numNextDaysShown = 0;
    }

    let from = 0 - numPreviousDaysShown;
    let until = daysInCurrentMonth + numNextDaysShown;

    const classNamePrefix = 'widget-day--';

    for (let i = from; i < until; i++) {
      const dayNumber = i + 1;
      const classNames = [];
      const style = {};
      let isDisabled = false;
      let type = '';
      let referenceDate = moment([year, month, 1]);

      if (dayNumber <= 0) {
        dayNumber = daysInPreviousMonth + i + 1;
        type = 'previous';
        referenceDate.subtract(1, 'month');
      }
      else if (dayNumber > daysInCurrentMonth) {
        dayNumber = i - daysInCurrentMonth + 1;
        type = 'next';
        referenceDate.add(1, 'month');
      }
      else {
        referenceDate.date(dayNumber);
      }

      // if (startDay) {
      //   style = { ...style, gridColumnStart: startDay};
      //   startDay = 0;
      // }

      if (type) {
        classNames.push(`${classNamePrefix}${type}`);
      }

      if (referenceDate.year() === selectedYear && referenceDate.month() === selectedMonth && dayNumber === selectedDay) {
        classNames.push(`${classNamePrefix}selected`);
      }
      else if (dayNumber === day && month === date.month() && year === date.year()) {
        classNames.push(`${classNamePrefix}current`);
      }

      if (this.checkIsInDisabledRange({ day: dayNumber, month: referenceDate.month(), year: referenceDate.year() })) {
        isDisabled = true;
        classNames.push(`${classNamePrefix}disabled`);
      }

      const clickAction = !isDisabled
        ? () => this.changeDay({ day: dayNumber, month: referenceDate.month(), year: referenceDate.year() })
        : () => {};

      list.push(
        <div className={`widget-day ${classNames.join(' ')}`} onClick={clickAction}
          style={style}
          key={i}
        >
          {dayNumber}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return list;
  }

  /**
   *  Disabled ranges = array of from, until
   *
   * @param {number} day
   * @param {number} month
   * @param {number} year
   */
  checkIsInDisabledRange({ day, month, year }) {
    const current = moment([year, month, day]);
    return _find(this.props.disabledRanges, range => {
      const from = moment([range.from.year, range.from.month, range.from.day]);
      const until = moment([range.until.year, range.until.month, range.until.day]);
      return current.isSameOrAfter(from) && current.isSameOrBefore(until);
    }) != null;
  }

  createDayLabels() {
    const list = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      const label = moment().day(i).format('ddd');
      list.push(<div className="widget-label" key={i}>{label}</div>)
    }
    return list;
  }

  createMonthSelector(current) {
    const list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      list.push({ value: i, label: moment().month(i).format('MMMM')});
    }
    return (
      <Dropdown onChange={(value) => this.changeMonth(value)} value={current} options={list} height={this.state.dropdownHeight} />
    );
  }

  createYearSelector(current) {
    const list = [];
    for (let i = MIN_YEAR; i < MAX_YEAR; i++) {
      list.push({ value: i, label: moment().year(i).format('YYYY')});
    }
    return (
      <Dropdown onChange={(value) => this.changeYear(value)} value={current} options={list} height={this.state.dropdownHeight} />
    );
  }

  changeDay({ day, month, year }) {
    console.log(day, month, year, moment([year, month, day]).format('DD MMM YYYY'));

    // let { month, year } = this.state;
    // let reference = moment([year, month, 1]);
    // const day = value + 1;
    // if (value < 0) {
    //   reference.subtract(1, 'month');
    //   reference.date(reference.daysInMonth() + day);
    // }
    // else {
    //   reference.date(day);
    // }
    // console.log(reference.date(), month, year);

    // moving to previous or next
    this.setState({ selectedDay: day, selectedMonth: month, selectedYear: year, month, year })
  }

  changeMonth(value) {
    this.setState({ month: value });
  }

  changeYear(value) {
    this.setState({ year: value })
  }

  previousMonth() {
    let { day, month, year } = this.state;
    const previousMonth = moment([year, month, day]).add(-1, 'month');
    this.setState({ day: previousMonth.date(), month: previousMonth.month(), year: previousMonth.year() });
  }

  nextMonth() {
    let { day, month, year } = this.state;
    const nextMonth = moment([year, month, day]).add(1, 'month');
    this.setState({ day: nextMonth.date(), month: nextMonth.month(), year: nextMonth.year() });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.dropdownHeight !== this.refs.body.clientHeight) {
      this.setState({ dropdownHeight: this.refs.body.clientHeight });
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ dropdownHeight: this.refs.body.clientHeight });
  }

  // onChangeField({ value, day, month, year }) {
  //   console.log('change', value, day, month, year);
  //   if (day && month && year) {
  //     this.setState({ selectedDay: day, selectedMonth: month, selectedYear: year });
  //   }
  // }

  onChangeField({ day, month, year, resolvedDate }) {
    if (resolvedDate && resolvedDate.isValid() && resolvedDate.year() >= MIN_YEAR && resolvedDate.year() <= MAX_YEAR) {
      this.changeDay({ day, month, year });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { day, month, year, date } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="date-picker">
        <DateField onChange={value => this.onChangeField(value)} />
        <div className="widget">
          <div className="header">
            <MonthNavigator onClick={() => this.previousMonth()} direction="left" />
            <div className="header-month">{this.createMonthSelector(month)}</div>
            <div className="header-year">{this.createYearSelector(year)}</div>
            <MonthNavigator onClick={() => this.nextMonth()} direction="right" />
          </div>
          <div className="widget-body" ref="body">
            {this.createDayLabels()}
            {this.createDays()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow! Your question mentions your overall goal, but it doesn't really give any specifics on what error or difficulty you are encountering. What part of the code are you having trouble with? What unexpected output? What errors? [Etc.](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Comment: The codesandbox is working fine. Are you looking for any specific beahviour?